# looping through a range of cells

Tags: vba, excel

I need to run the function AddColumnofData on each cell from c27 and every contiguous non empty cell to the right, but I get a "Run-time error 424 object required", any help woul dbe greatly appreciated.

```
Set col = Range("$C$27", Range("$C$27").End(xlToRight))

For Each c In col
    AddColumnofData (c)
Next c
```

Comment: what does `AddColumnofData` do - we may be able to optimise your function speed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the assumption you have defined `AddColumnofData` as

```
Sub AddColumnofData(c As Range)
    ...
End Sub
```

your call to it needs to be

```
AddColumnofData c
```

(that is, remove the brackets)

Jesse's advice to `DIM` your variables, while not not manditory is good advice.  Applies to `col` as well.  To make it manditory add `Option Explicit` to the top of your module.

Comment: See also [this link on Chip Pearson's](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/byrefbyval.aspx) on how to use (or not) the parentheses when calling another sub

Answer (score 1):

You can declare or set your range objects before passing them to your function. To prove that you are passing the correct values to your function, try this.

```
Dim r As Range '-- if you don't declare it as a range type you get a variant type as default
Dim c As Range '-- this is used to store the single cell in the For Each loop

Set r = Range("A1:D1") '-- substitute your range as per your example

For Each c In r '-- you could also use r.cells

    MsgBox c.Value '-- pass to your function instead of a call to the Message Box

Next
```

This produces a series of 4 Message Boxes containing the values in cells A1 to D1 of the active worksheet, if your Range "r" is seriously large then pass it to Debug.Print instead.

Comment: why declare and set the objects before calling the function? The advantage is that you can do some validation on the cells in the range first, you can concatenate cell values etc. You can also pass the value as a string instead of a range. so your function can deal with a string function instead of a range object.

Answer (score 0):

If you declare c:

```
Dim c as Range
```

Then what you have should work.